# Textarea is not displaying the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I have a textarea which will be in hidden state when the request comes to the page and once i select the value in the page i call a controller method which does manipilation and returns the response to the same page and in the ajax success method i try to print the response in the textarea

This is my gsp page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Json Compare</title>
<g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery"
    src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" />
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.testMe').click(function(){
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL) 
            alert(firstText.value)
            alert(secondText.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
                success: function(data){              
                    var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert("Parsed Values are: "+retrievedValue)
                    alert("Values are: "+retrievedValue.status)
                    //alert("success: "+retrievedValue.result)
                    if (retrievedValue.status===true) {
                        alert("inside the success: "+retrievedValue.result)
                        alert("the parsed values 1st data"+data.firstText)
                        $("#result").css("display","block")
                         $("#result").val(data.firstText)
                        //notice .html since it is content of textArea
                        //$('.textarea').html(retrievedValue.result)
                        //document.getElementById("textarea").style.display = "block"
                        //document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = data.result
                         //$('#textarea').val(retrievedValue.result).show()
                        // $('.textarea').css("display","");
                        //$('#result').attr('style', 'display:block'); 
                        //$('#testdiv').show()
                        //$('.textarea').toggle();
                        // $('#testdiv').attr('style', 'display:block'); 
                        //$('#testdiv').removeAttr("style");
                        //document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";

                    } else { /// if (data===false ) {
                        alert("Failure: "+retrievedValue.value1+" "+retrievedValue.value2)
                       //$('#result1').html(entry.value1).show()
                     // $('#result2').html(entry.value2).show()
                    } 
                }
            });

        });

    });
    //event.preventDefault(); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <g:form>
        <div>
            <label>From Time</label>
            <g:select name="firstText" from="${eventsList}" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']" />
            <label>To Time</label>
            <g:select name="secondText" from="${eventsList}" noSelection="['':'-Choose the To Date-']" />
            <button class="testMe">Compare</button>
        </div>
        <br>

        <textarea id="result" style="display: none"></textarea>

        <%--<div id="textarea">
                <label>Output</label><br> 
                     <textArea id="result" name="myField" /> 
                    <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

    --%></g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

once the result is displayed immediately it disappears how to stop it. And also how to display the result different textarea based on the response from the controller. Initially the textarea should not be visible

Comment: use `firstText` and `secondText` as `id` not as `name` in the label tag. then use `$('#firstText').val()` to get the value of firstText (same goes for secondText)

Comment: @siam i have edited the code is it correct? tried to run it still it is same like the result is displayed in the text area and disappears immediately

Comment: @raghulc this site is to help you understand something and make you go away and think about it. A lot of people have answered you in various ways and all of which has had you copying methods then suggesting it doesn't work. I think if you want to learn you need to take away what people say and sit back think / test and work / devise something from it. I still state this is homework since i see no particular reason as to why response `box` has to be a `textArea` that is what makes me feel its trickery and more likely assignment work. So rather than expecting people to copy paste research subjec

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        $('.testMe').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL)
            alert(firstText.value)
            alert(secondText.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
                success: function(data){
                    //alert("success"+data.value)
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#result").val(data).show()

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: he's not even using `.text()`

Comment: @vahid i will try as you had mentioned in the other question and let you know

Comment: @vahid i tried the code that you mentiond and it does not work. the alert inside the success function of ajax is not firing. i.e does not come inside if (data.success===true) {

Comment: The result immediately disappears because the button performs a submit by default. To prevent this from happening then you should use the `preventDefault()` function @raghulc

Comment: @raghul you are responding to another question on this question ? multi dimensions to this basic problem ? why don't you enable println in controller and `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and debug and figure out what is going on with the response ?

Comment: @vahid i am getting the response in my success function the problem is it is not displaying it in the textarea the text area is not visible once i get the response from my controller

Comment: @Azola i used the preventDefault() but the text area is not visible once i get a responce from my controller

Comment: @Azola now the button is not submitting

Answer (score 0):

Treat a `textArea` like a `div`

```
$('#textArea').html('content');
```

Unless you declare:

```
<g:textArea value="something" />
```

Which then behaves differently to a standard textArea if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this.. hopefully it'll work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.testMe').click(function() {
    var URL = "${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
    var firstText = $('#firstText');
    var secondText = $('#secondText');
    alert(URL);
    alert(firstText.val());
    alert(secondText.val());
    $.ajax({
      url: URL,
      data: {
        firstText: firstText.val(),
        secondText: secondText.val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //alert("success"+data.value)
        console.log(data);
        $("#result").val(data);
        $("#result").show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this is the code i am using success: function(data){
                 var data = JSON.parse(data);
                   
                 alert("Values are"+data.status)
                
                  if (data.status===true) {
                      alert("success1"+data.result)
                     $('#result').val(data.result)
                     $('#result').show()
                  } else { /// if (data===false ) {
                        
                  } 
                }

Comment: alert is displaying the values

Comment: it would be nice if you create a fiddle and share the link. it'll help us to solve the issue more easily.

Answer (score 0):

And if you try to append the `textarea` element dynamically? For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testMe').click(function(){

        // ... your code ...

        // ajax part
        $.ajax({
            url:URL,
            data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
            success: function(data){
                var textarea_el = $('<textarea />', {
                    id: 'result',
                    text: data.value // or just data?
                });

                // change form_selector with the real selector!
                $(<form_selector>).append(textarea_el);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is this what excatly i need to put in my code  var textarea_el = $('<textarea />', {

Comment: also what does $(<form_selector>).append(textarea_el); mean

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.testMe').click(function(){
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL)
            alert(firstText.value)
            alert(secondText.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
                success: function(data){
                    //alert("success"+data.value)
                    console.log(data);
                   $("#result").css("display","block")
                    $("#result").val(data.firstText)

                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

try above code 
**if it not ,try to alert(data.firstText) check the return value in alert .whether it is object or value**

Comment: when i tried alert("the parsed values 1st data"+data.firstText) the alert is not fired

Comment: alert(data[0].firstText) try this

Comment: i need more information whether it is returning array or?.................

Comment: i am parsing the retrieved value var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);. so the alert alert("Values are: "+retrievedValue.status) has true value and alert("inside the success: "+retrievedValue.result) has value "The Json are Equal and no MisMatch" as i have hardcoded the value